# add button to perform an action prior to sending to view page

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm working on a program that is a reservation service for lab systems using Yii2.0.  I've been using Yii for a little while but for some reason this one is stumping me

I have all of the systems listed in a gridview and I'd like to have a button in the actionColumn that will run the 'reserve' action and then show the view for the individual system.

I have the button added and it brings the user to the view page but I don't know what I need to do to have it run the reserve action first...or if it's even possible.  I've tried pointing it to the reserve action in the controller but of course that looks for a view page rather than an action.

Here's some of the code from what I've been trying after looking through many pages of suggestions:

**On the index page**

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{reserve}',
                'buttons' => [
                        'reserve' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>',
                                $url,
                                [
                                        'title' => 'Reserve',
                                        'data-method' => 'post',
                                        'data-pjax' => 0,
                        ]);
                        }                   
                ],

        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            return Url::toRoute(['cml/view', 'id' => $key]);
        }
```

**Function in Controller**

```
    public function actionReserve($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->fkReservedTo == 1)
    {
        $model->fkReservedTo = Yii::$app->user->id;
        // shouldn't you call save here
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$id]);
    }
    else 
    {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'This system is not available to be reserved');
        return $this->showAlert();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: an action is a function  .. if you need  execute a function before render a view just call the function ..of place the code you need  in  function and the call the function where/when you need .

Comment: you are already directly calling the `actionReserve` in the `anchor` link what are you trying to ask? and what is the error or abnormal behavior you are encountering

Comment: I thought that was the case also but it's looking for a view page called reserve rather than calling the actionReserve function.

Comment: did it solve or not

Comment: The main issue was that I didn't have the access control setup correctly for the action.  I did have to use the change suggested by Irfan and I tried to vote for that as an answer but since my reputation is so low, it didn't seem to do anything.  Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: To be clear on what fixed the issue for me, there were a few things.  I didn't have the access control setup for the Reserve action.  I also used Irfan's suggestions of changing the Url and adding the 'id' argument to the redirect.

This is now working as I'd hoped.  Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return Url::toRoute(['cml/view', 'id' => $key]);
```

to

```
return Url::toRoute(['cml/reserve', 'id' => $key]);
```

in your `urlCreator` function.

Comment: When I change the urlCreator function, I get an error stating that the view file does not exist.  I'd like to avoid creating a view file for the reserve function.  My goal is to have the actionReserve function run (which would update the fkReservedTo column with the user id of the currently logged in user) and then show the view page.  As you can see, I have the function redirect to the view page for the system once the change is made.  Basically, I just want the function to run when the button is clicked and not to be taken directly to the view page.

Comment: that means it is going to else block and calling `showAlert()` function, not sure what is your implementation for `showAlert()`, can you please share.
Also within `if` block
change `return $this->redirect(['view']);` to ` return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $id]);`

Comment: Sorry...I'm not sure how to put the code in the comments correctly/**
     * Action to show alertPage.php
     * This page is setup to show each type
     * of flash message
     * @return alertPage
     */
    public function showAlert()
    {
     return $this->render('alertPage');
    }

Comment: @GregRoberge if you are trying to avoid the view should not be called try adding `Yii::$app->end()` or `return` at the end of the function. it wont call the view and you have used the alert view in wrong way you should try using [**`yii\bootstrap\Alerts`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-alert.html)  provided by yii2 framework you can include them in the layout and just add the flash message and redirect it will automatically show the message

Comment: I think I have this figured out.  I forgot to add the 'reserve' action to the access Control list in web.php.  I did that and now it's at least getting into the function.

I saw the error message about not having a view but didn't look further down where it said that it was processing another error.  The other error was 'access denied'.  Thank you for attempting to help.  Sorry if it wasted your time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, accept my answer if it helped in any way.

Comment: I tried to vote for the answer but since I don't have much reputation, it doesn't look like it helped anything.  I also saw your message about calling save (the edit in the code) so I've included that in my program.

Thank you for the help.